# Why is there no information regarding testing a database for consistency? Can't find any resources on the matter

Tags: database, testing

About a year ago I discovered that it was extremely useful to test the database consistency/state on a big data type project I was working on. I've later applied this technique to other more general applications and found it to be as equally crucial. I tried to google around for database testing and only found that the majority of the articles talked about unit testing stored procs, I was expecting to see books dedicated to the subject but haven't even found a single article. I'm wondering if I'm searching for something that already exists but is known by a different name.

Let me explain with a few examples of what I mean by database tests:

1. Testing that your database is not in an invalid state by validating business logic rules were applied (database check constraints have limitations to what they can enforce).
   a. You have a list of flags and/or values and certain combinations are invalid. e.g. A bank
   account with -500 or less balance must have a status of 'NOTINGOODSTANDING' if there exists a user account with a balance of -500.1 and he is in good standing then something went wrong. 
   b. Testing that values are within certain ranges, e.g. a price is non negative. While we can get rid of this possibility by a check constraint, the database may not support check constraints or it might be a legacy database that never had that constraint put in place.

*Why test for these factors if your program validates these conditions? These validation rules might have been bypassed due to a bug, another application modifying the data, someone running a bad sql script directly on the server, or maybe your database was modified by a malicious user who ran some sql injection.

2. Testing for potentially duplicate values (e.g. duplicate customers, orders, etc..)
3. Validating partial/incomplete data, e.g. if you have a list of customers with missing data (such as email addressed) because your system allows for partial data insertions, you want to validate that before a mass email gets sent out all the customers have had email addresses inputted (and if not maybe talk to the data entry people and see why they missed a few).

The list goes on but hopefully that should give a basic idea.

Note that these tests are purely informational and not preventative, they merely tell you when something has might have gone wrong.

Does anyone else find any value in these types of testing? Is it already a well established practice?

Comment: I'm not clear on how this is different from integration testing. It's also not clear on the scope of what you're trying to do--if you want to retroactively ensure data is "consistent" based on your app's rules, and you can have *other* things going in and mucking with the data, then you need to check for validity on reads as well as writes, *and* have something that is constantly sweeping the DB for essentially all data and ensuring it has *remained* correct across all time, since not every piece of data will be touched regularly.

Comment: Seems like you got it, since there are potentially other sources for data modification (other applications, malicious users, etc..) we do need something that sweeps regularly to ensure that data is consistent with business rules. This can be a nightly check or weekend depending on the size of the database. I've never heard of such a concept in an article or book, I was just wondering why.

Comment: Because if you allow arbitrary data munging and you screw it up it's your own fault. Fat-fingering production data isn't generally allowed to happen at the admin level. It could also take days to actually do this depending on what you're really talking about. It's the same as everything else--there's an ROI, and in general, I think something like this would have a fairly low return. YMMV.

Comment: That depends, your assuming there is only one system in place. Imagine a scenario where there are multiple different systems that interact with the same data. You might not have built any of those systems previously but it still might be important to verify that the database is consistent and will continue to be. Another issue is security, if somehow the system was compromised a database checking system might catch that.

Comment: No, I *explicitly* stated "you can have other things going in and mucking with the data" and "arbitrary data munging". If that's the case I don't believe you should be directly manipulating the data but should have all manipulation occur through a service that enforces validity. If you're waiting until the DB layer to detect security breaches it's far, *far* too late, and you're doing security wrong. As far as my history with systems involving multiple actors, I'm certain the number of players in some of the systems I've worked with exceed anything reasonable.

Comment: I agree that a service would certainly be best practice but there are scenarios where a service just simply does not exist. if for example one of these systems is a legacy application. And even if there was a service it does not prohibit there being a bug within the validation or persistence layer. In the case of a sql injection attack it might be easiest to catch it in the database to see if any validation rules have been violated.

Comment: If there's a bug in the validation or persistence layer then your testing is broken. If you're vulnerable to SQL injection it's *definitely* being done wrong. You need a code audit and automated testing. If a service doesn't exist then create one--that's the point, and it would explicitly prevent most of the scenarios you're discussing other than someone fat-fingering the data directly.

Comment: Creating a service might not be realistic depending on the scope, rewriting fortran, etc.. applications to use the service instead of the database is even less realistic. Maybe your testing might be 'broken', tests will never catch all your bugs and how would you validate persistence without looking at the database?

Comment: Integration testing, as stated. A sweeper running through the DB would take more time than reporting, *particularly* on organic legacy systems with complex relations. To validate all the data of a previous jobs' legacy DBs would take on the order of many weeks or possibly months. You throw "legacy" and "Fortran" around while refusing to acknowledge that it's precisely because of those words that it isn't feasible and you'll need to rely on good reporting of errors during data processing, more discipline moving forward, and retrofitting to run validation as a service.

Comment: You make a good point about using validating a second time during reads/processing data. But again you can only do that within your own application, if for example there is an existing legacy system which is responsible for displaying orders to warehouse staff for shipping, instead of changing fortran code or rewriting a potentially complex application you could run a simple test to check for invalid addresses and notify the appropriate people or flag them to recheck the data.